# How to handle this array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm not getting how to manage this array.

```
Array ( 
    [Event] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [Date] => DateTime 
            [Description] => test 
            [CurrentValue] => 31/12/2010 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [Date] => DateTime 
            [Description] => test 
            [PreviousValue] => 1 
            [CurrentValue] => 2 
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "manage this array"?

Comment: what is your expectation ?

Comment: `$array['Event'][0]['Date']`?

Comment: I can nog get any output out of the foreach :(

Comment: What foreach? I only see an array.

Comment: Show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there.

Comment: I did it in a while loop and $arr['Event'][$i]['Date'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multi-dimensinal array. If by handle you mean access the data in it, you simply use more square brackets to specify which bit you mean:

```
echo $yourArray['event'][0]['CurrentValue'];
```

output:

> 31/12/2010

And so on.

If by handle you mean to insert data, it is the same thing.

When you run a foreach, it will take elements from the *outer-most* array. This means if you want to check elements further in, you will have to either nest foreach statements or call a function in a recursive manner to get to the bottom most layer of array data.

Answer (score 1):

A multi-dimensional array in PHP can be handled the following way. Yours is a 3D one.

`$array['Event'][0]['Date']` would give you Datetime (Description) i.e. test

To get the data, you would need to use nested `foreach` loops.

For example, a outer loop Event..and so on, then inside one more loop, and then again one more.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested for loops.

### [demo](https://eval.in/156180)

```
  foreach($your_array as $k =>$v){ //main array
        foreach($v as $k1 =>$v1){ //event array
          foreach($v1 as $k2 =>$v2){ //event sub array
          echo "key: " .$k2 ." value: ". $v2."\n";
        }     
        }
    }
```

**Program Output**

```
key: Date value:  DateTime
key: Description value:  test 
key: CurrentValue value:  31/12/2010
key: Date value: DateTime
key: Description value:  test
key: PreviousValue value:  1 
key: CurrentValue value:
```

Comment: Thx! this puts me back on the right track!